# How to insert a youtube video as an attachment to specified timeline item?

Tags: google-mirror-api

Currently attachment takes stream for the content, is it possible to set a youtube video url for the attachment?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049889/google-mirror-api-video/16050044#16050044

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet possible with the current version of the API and Glass client. Feel free to file a feature request on our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to stream a youtube video in the timeline card, here is the C#.Net code. use this name space "YoutubeExtractor".This works fine for me. When getting the youtube video url get the link that comes after you select share.

```
 private static String InsertItem5(MainController controller)
    {

        string link = "http://youtu.be/9uYKISlL7Vg";
        IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(link);
        VideoInfo video = videoInfos.First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 360);
        String vLink = video.DownloadUrl;


        TimelineItem critical = new TimelineItem()
        {

            Text = "Menu Card",
            BundleId = "666",
            Notification = new NotificationConfig() { Level = "DEFAULT" },
            MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>()
                                     {
                                         new MenuItem() {Action = "DELETE"},
                                     }

        };

        String mediaLink = vLink;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaLink))
        {
            Stream stream = null;
            if (mediaLink.StartsWith("/"))
            {
                stream = new StreamReader(controller.Server.MapPath(mediaLink)).BaseStream;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(mediaLink) as HttpWebRequest;

                request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;


                HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                byte[] b = null;
                using (Stream streamFromWeb = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        count = streamFromWeb.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                        ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
                    } while (streamFromWeb.CanRead && count > 0);
                    b = ms.ToArray();

                    stream = new MemoryStream(b);
                }
            }
            controller.Service.Timeline.Insert(critical, stream, "video/mp4").Upload();
        }
        else
        {
            controller.Service.Timeline.Insert(critical).Fetch();
        }
```